# How to import specific package from Go module?

Tags: go, module, package, versioning, dependency-management

Golang 1.11beta2 introduced experimental support for [Modules](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules).

I am failing to import a specific package from a go module.

This is the error when building the application:

```
$ go install
go: downloading github.com/udhos/modhello/modlib/lib v1.0.0
go: finding github.com/udhos/modhello latest
go: import "github.com/udhos/modhello/modapp" ->
    import "github.com/udhos/modhello/modlib/lib": cannot find module providing package github.com/udhos/modhello/modlib/lib
```

Why is the import shown above failing?

This is the package 'lib' from module 'modlib':

```
# repo: modhello
# module: modlib
# package: lib
$ cat modhello/modlib/lib/modlib.go
package lib
func Sum(a, b int) int {
    return a + b
}
$ cat modhello/modlib/go.mod
module github.com/udhos/modhello/modlib
```

This is the application 'modapp' :

```
$ cat modhello/modapp/main.go
package main
import (
        "log"
        "github.com/udhos/modhello/modlib/lib"
)
func main() {
        run(1, 2)
}
func run(a, b int) {
        log.Printf("Sum(%d,%d) = %d", a, b, lib.Sum(a, b))
}
$ cat modhello/modapp/go.mod
module github.com/udhos/modhello/modapp
require github.com/udhos/modhello/modlib v1.0.0
```

The git repository is tagged with 'modlib/v1.0.0'. This is how one publishes a version for a module.

Go version:

```
$ go version
go version go1.11beta2 linux/amd64
$ git --version
git version 2.18.0
```

I have posted this doubt also on [golang-nuts](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/golang-nuts): [Host two distinct modules in one git repo?](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/golang-nuts/W3e5MTwC7Js/discussion)

Comment: It's a beta feature, it may have defects.

Comment: @Adrian yeah, But it may work as well. Real question is, what is a correct way of importing specific package for a module? If i am doing it correctly, I would open a bug report. Otherwise, how to do it?

Comment: @Peter It does: https://github.com/udhos/modhello/blob/master/modlib/lib/modlib.go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`go clean -modcache` fixed the issue.

More details here: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/26695